# Keycloak mysql standalone getting errors with JHipster/Angular generated app

Tags: jhipster, openid, keycloak

I am using JHipster to generate (online) an Angular and Spring Boot project. I can get everything to run when I use Keycloak as a docker image with an H2 in-memory database (this is the default hello world example). I have downloaded and setup Keycloak as a standalone app that connects to MySQL. I believe it is working correctly because I can see my Keycloak database being updated in MySQL.

In Keycloak I have added a new realm, "Acme." I have created a new client called "web_app." I am not sure what all information is needed for you to help me understand my error. I have created a user within Keycloak, myname@acme.com (I am disguising this for this Stackoverflow post) with a simple password.

When I login to my client app, which redirects me to Keycloak, as the email/password user, or when I login as a Google/Facebook user, I get the same error shown below.

[image: Login Error]

The code I found in Keycloak with this error message is below, "[not_allowed] Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client."

```
public AccessTokenResponseBuilder generateRefreshToken() {
    if (accessToken == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("accessToken not set");
    }

    ClientScopeModel offlineAccessScope = KeycloakModelUtils.getClientScopeByName(realm, OAuth2Constants.OFFLINE_ACCESS);
    boolean offlineTokenRequested = offlineAccessScope==null ? false : clientSessionCtx.getClientScopeIds().contains(offlineAccessScope.getId());
    if (offlineTokenRequested) {
        UserSessionManager sessionManager = new UserSessionManager(session);
        if (!sessionManager.isOfflineTokenAllowed(clientSessionCtx)) {
            event.error(Errors.NOT_ALLOWED);
            throw new ErrorResponseException("not_allowed", "Offline tokens not allowed for the user or client", Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        refreshToken = new RefreshToken(accessToken);
        refreshToken.type(TokenUtil.TOKEN_TYPE_OFFLINE);
        sessionManager.createOrUpdateOfflineSession(clientSessionCtx.getClientSession(), userSession);
    } else {
        refreshToken = new RefreshToken(accessToken);
        refreshToken.expiration(getRefreshExpiration());
    }
    refreshToken.id(KeycloakModelUtils.generateId());
    refreshToken.issuedNow();
    return this;
}
```

When I login as email/password I get this error via Keycloak logs.

```
21:11:55,478 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=acme, clientId=web_app, userId=7e361802-83ac-4441-8e8e-a2c431b3d542, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=not_allowed, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=930ce6f2-4324-40d6-9ba1-de36a93d30c4, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

When I login as Google provider I get this error via Keycloak logs.

```
21:20:20,574 WARN  [org.keycloak.connections.httpclient.DefaultHttpClientFactory] (default task-4) Truststore is disabled
21:20:44,307 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-4) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=acme, clientId=web_app, userId=9dd5c436-299a-409c-9232-442218f9f41b, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=not_allowed, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=6847b494-86b6-4046-a81f-bb40c911e1e9, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Below are the URLs and ports I am using.

```
Angular Client: http://localhost:9000
Spring Boot Server: http://localhost:8081
Keycloak: http://localhost:8080
```

Below is my Keycloak, clients, web_app settings. Let me know what else to share to help debug this.

[image: Keycloak -> Clients -> Web_app client settings]

I want this JHipster (Angular/Spring Boot) to work with Keycloak as a standalone environment because the sample docker image with in-memory H2 database will not meet my needs in production. The docker image is great as a sandbox or proof of concept, but I need to get this standalone MySQL environment working. I may have to use Okta, but they do not support Twitter login, so I am trying to get Keycloak working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try importing the generated Keycloak config from `src/main/docker/realm-config`? That should set the realm to the same as JHipster expects

Comment: I tried to import the src/main/docker/realm-config/jhipster-realm.json into my standalone instance of Keycloak, rebooted all running apps, and I still get the same error upon logging in. I will keep trying with this import. Thanks.

Comment: I now have this working, but I am not certain as to why. I am thinking this issue had something to do with offline_access as a role or not having a client scope for a new realm I created. I will keep an eye on this.